# Is it possible to see output from log cat without having the app source code?

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat, android-logcat, android-studio-2.0

I have an app installed on my device. 
An app that I developed, but I haven't got the source code anymore.

Is it possible to attach log cat to this app?

Comment: Yes, you just have to manually filter logcat for your app in android studio by using the package name

Comment: As the comments and answers already point out, yes. That being said, if this app is downloaded / available on Google Play, then all Logs should ideally be **disabled**. Similar to how you can see logs in the logcat, other users (_with knowledge of course_) can too. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

yes you can, just enable usb debugging on your android device, and plug the device where you have the application installed on it, by that, you will see all the logs on logcat.

Answer (score 1):

Depends if you've left logs in the code. If you did, the easiest method would be probably going into your Android Studio and checking you Android Monitor tab. You can switch devices / applications there.

[image: android studio logcat]

If you don't have any logs and your question actually means you want to add some logs in, then I'm afraid you can't reliably do that.